# React router changes url but not context is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-context

I have a page template that contains a bunch of different keys that are used to show text in a language selected by the user. The default language is English, the corresponding URL for the English page is `localhost:3000`. Users have the option to switch to Spanish by clicking on a button. When a user clicks the button in order to switch to Spanish the `history.push()` function is invoked. It updates the URL with the given country code, in this case the URL becomes `localhost:3000/es`. When clicking the browsers back button the URL changes back to `localhost:3000` but the view remains in the Spanish language.

I struggled with this issue for some time now and tried to implement multiple solutions, among them are:

- Wrapping the component using the `WithRouter` component;
- Pass the history object as a prop using the `Router` component;
- Force update the component using `componentDidUpdate`;
- Call dispatch in the `App` component;

My `index.js` file contains the routes that render the `AppWrapper` component. The `AppWrapper` component renders the `App` component that is a child of the `I18nContextProvider` component.

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';
import { I18nContextProvider, availableTranslationsEnum } from './languages/languageHandler';

const AppWrapper = (language) => (
  <I18nContextProvider language={language}>
    <App />
  </I18nContextProvider>
);

const appRoutes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path={`/${availableTranslationsEnum.spanish}`}
        render={() => AppWrapper(availableTranslationsEnum.spanish)}
        exact
      />
      <Route
        render={() => AppWrapper(availableTranslationsEnum.english)}
      />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(appRoutes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The `I18nContextProvider` component is defined in the `languageHandler.js` file that looks like this.

```
//languageHandler.js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import EN from './en.json';
import ES from './es.json';

const translations = {
  en: EN,
  es: ES,
};

const getTranslate = (langCode) => (key) => translations[langCode][key] || key;

export const availableTranslationsEnum = {
  english: Object.keys(translations)[0],
  spanish: Object.keys(translations)[1],
};

const setInitialState = (language) => {
  const defaultLanguage = availableTranslationsEnum.english;
  const siteLanguage = language || defaultLanguage;
  return {
    langCode: siteLanguage,
    translate: getTranslate(siteLanguage),
  };
};

export const I18nContext = React.createContext(setInitialState());

export const I18nContextProvider = ({ children, language }) => {
  const reducer = (action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'setLanguage':
        return {
          langCode: action.payload,
          translate: getTranslate(action.payload),
        };
      default:
        return { ...setInitialState(language) };
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, setInitialState(language));

  return (
    <I18nContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </I18nContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The `App` component contains the translations keys and looks like this.

```
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { I18nContext } from './languages/languageHandler';
import LanguageSelect from './components/LanguageSelect';

const App = () => {
  const { translate } = React.useContext(I18nContext);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <LanguageSelect />
        <p>
          {translate('edit_and_save')}
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          {translate('learn_react')}
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The `App` component renders the `LanguageSelect` component and looks like this.

```
//LanguageSelect.js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { I18nContext, availableTranslationsEnum } from '../languages/languageHandler';

const LanguageSelect = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { langCode, dispatch } = useContext(I18nContext);

  const switchLanguage = (languageToSwitchTo) => {
    const dispatchType = 'setLanguage';
    dispatch({ type: dispatchType, payload: languageToSwitchTo });
    if (languageToSwitchTo !== availableTranslationsEnum.english) {
      history.push(`/${languageToSwitchTo}`);
    }

    if (languageToSwitchTo === availableTranslationsEnum.english) {
      history.push(`/`); //Default language
    }

  };

  if (langCode === availableTranslationsEnum.english) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => switchLanguage(availableTranslationsEnum.spanish)}>Español</button>
    );
  }

  return (<button onClick={() => switchLanguage(availableTranslationsEnum.english)}>English</button>);
};

export default LanguageSelect;
```

I'm trying to understand why the URL is changing but the component stays the way it is. If anyone can help me push me in the right direction it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use react dev tools to inspect component's **props and states** - no changes, no reason to rerendering.

Your reducer works for 'events' ... changing url (back button) results in **prop change**, not action dispatch.

`<I18nContext.Provider>` uses **state, not props** - remains unchanged on prop change, no reason to rerender.

Just inspect props and update render functions to be props changes aware.

Answer (score 0):

Add your language value to the **basename** prop to the `<BrowserRouter>` component, and it will create a base path for all of your routes.

```js
const appRoutes = props => (
  <BrowserRouter basename={props.language}>
    <I18nContextProvider language={props.language}>
      <App />
    </I18nContextProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

if the language was English, then your URL will be:

```
localhost:3000/en
```

And also for other languages that you have and the basename doesn't change. by the user by using **push** function.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How to come by the value of the language and how can adding a basename update the component once a user clicks the browsers back button?

Comment: There is no need to check the back button, just you should connect your app component to your store to get selected language and add it as a basename to the BrowserRoute component.

Comment: When changing my code to  `<BrowserRouter basename={props.language}><I18nContextProvider language ={props.language}><App /></I18nContextProvider>
</BrowserRouter>` it throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property edit_and_save of undefined` referencing to `getTranslate()` in `languageHandler.js`.